# Can't Install MySQL With Xampp

Tags: mysql, logging, xampp, installation

Noob here and have no idea what I'm doing. Any advice?

This is what I can see - https://i.stack.imgur.com/18ke4.png

[image: mysql error]

**This is the text incase you cannot read it**

22:40:32  [mysql]   Problem detected!
22:40:32  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MySQL57"!
22:40:32  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
22:40:32  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
22:40:32  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
22:40:32  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...

**This be the Log -**

[image]

Any help would be really really appreciated. Thank you guys

Comment: Status change detected: stopped
01:03:46  [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
01:03:46  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
01:03:46  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
01:03:46  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
01:03:46  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
01:03:46  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the Port:

> To change the MySQL port for XAMPP:
>
> You need to stop XAMPP server then  open my.ini file located at:
>   xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini
>
> You will fine port entries on couple of lines there you can change the
>   default port 3306 to something like 3307
>
> Start XAMPP server.

Found here : https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-the-port-of-a-MySQL-server-in-XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

Before you start changing ports as per other suggestions here, as a nearly-noob myself, can I suggest you try one other bit of fault finding 1st...
Check the notifications area in the standard Windows system tray... do you have multiple XAMPP icons showing there?
I managed to dig myself into a hole by crashing out of the Control Panel, leaving Apache running on more than a few occasions and the next time I restarted the CP I'd get the "port in use" kind of reponse...
If you do have multiple instances, right click each on and use the options you then see to stop the MySQL processes. Any extra XAMPP option which is showing all  services stopped you can then tell to quit.
After that, you may get a clean restart of the Control Panel without needing to change any port settings.